# windows phone 7 xml response handling

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, rest, serialization

I have an application that makes use of an API from a website. It returns this xml:

```
<xml>
  <id>48</id>
  <name>Nuno Horta</name>
  <user_lvl>2</user_lvl>
</xml>
```

my code is this one:

```
client.ExecuteAsync(request, response => {
                            var value = response.Content;
                            XElement loadedData = XElement.Parse(value);
                            var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("xml")
                                       select new 
                                       {
                                           id = (int)query.Element("id"),
                                           name = (string)query.Element("name"),
                                       };
                            listBox.ItemsSource = data;
});
```

i want to get those two values, id and name, to save them on the app settings so i was trying to show them here:

```
<TextBlock Text="XML Data:"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="10" >
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                   </ListBox>
```

By the way i am using restsharp to make the request
no success...any ideas to get those values? i need to do this with other 3 api methods requests. Thanks!

Comment: And what happens? What is the type of "data"?

Comment: It doesnt happen anything..i was expecting to get both values(id and name) to do something with them. data its just a var to databinding so i can show the values on textblocks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your databindings to use Path since you are binding to properties of the items.

so your xaml should be

```
<TextBlock Text="XML Data:"/>  
            <ListBox x:Name="listBox">  
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <StackPanel Margin="10" >  
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=name}"/>  
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=id}"/>  
                        </StackPanel>  
                    </DataTemplate>  
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>  
               </ListBox>
```

More information about path binding is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)